# "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\InvoicesExport' not found" in Maatwebsite Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In my Laravel Project i use Maatwebsite\Excel for to export Data in Excel format. i use New Version 3.0 (Maatwebsite\Excel)

**App/Exports.php**

```
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Purchasepaymenttransaction;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class InvoicesExport implements FromView
{
    public function view(): View
    {
            $purchasepayment=Purchasepaymenttransaction::Where('transaction_category',2)->OrderBy('transaction_date','DESC')->get();

        return view('exports.purchasepayments', [
            'purchasepayment' => $purchasepayment
        ]);
    }
}
```

**In my Payment Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Purchasepaymenttransaction;
use Excel;
use App\Exports;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    public function purchaseexport()
        {

            return Excel::download(new InvoicesExport, 'invoices.xlsx');
        }

}
```

i got "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\InvoicesExport' not found" Error

Comment: you are probably missing a `use` statement.

Comment: use InvoicesExport; in your controller

Comment: it return Class 'App\InvoicesExport' not found @KuldeepMishra

Comment: In your Payment controller add this `use` statement. `use App\Exports\InvoicesExport;`

Comment: yes Use App\InvoicesExport;

Comment: same error display "Class 'App\InvoicesExport' not found" @KuldeepMishra

Comment: Class 'App\Exports\InvoicesExport' not found error will be display @ab_ab

Comment: your class name and file name differs. try rename Exports.php to InvoicesExport.php

Comment: "Class 'App\InvoicesExport' not found" error will be display after renaming @ab_ab

Comment: use this `use App\Exports\InvoicesExport;`

Comment: does it works? @Karthik

Comment: I already used that one use App\Exports\InvoicesExport; but same class not found error will be display @ab_ab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170652/discussion-between-ab-ab-and-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

```
return Excel::download(new \InvoicesExport, 'invoices.xlsx');
```

Normally you use backslash('\') before class when you get class not found exception. It will automatically find that class from your code and use it where you need and don't require to use it at top of file. It is similar to

```
use [YOUR_PATH]/InvoicesExport
```

If you use "use" statement then no need to backslash('\'). You can use any of above two. It will work.

Comment: Thanks for providing code which might help solve the problem, but generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.

Comment: i added description, check it  out

Answer (score 0):

use App\Exports\InvoicesExport as ExportsInvoicesExport;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31915809)

Answer (score 0):

Update the upper part of your Payment controller  to this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Purchasepaymenttransaction;
use App\Exports\InvoicesExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

then you are done.Also, update the line in your InvoicesExport file from `use App\Purchasepaymenttransaction;` to `use App\Models\Purchasepaymenttransaction;`